# What we should write in roman for ordinal numbers?

Tags: numbers, ordinal-numbers

As we write 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th what we should write in roman for the same way?

Comment: Nowadays, Roman numerals are used for ordinals in the first place. So, just V would mean "fifth" rather than "five"

Comment: Monarchs and popes are identified by plain Roman numerals, so Henry VIII is read as 'Henry the Eighth'.